# heredoc prompts not passed in

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm trying to automate the creation of a PostgreSQL user with a bash script.

I'm specifying the initial password as prompted by the "createuser" command, and I'd like to do it in bash, which I think implies a here document.

Yet the prompt answers I've specified don't make it to the "createuser" command!  Here is directly entering the script on the command line:

```
-bash-4.1$ createuser mynewuser -P <<ENDBEFORETHIS
> fakepassword
> fakepassword
> n
> n
> n
> ENDBEFORETHIS
Enter password for new role: 
-bash-4.1$
```

Why is that?

- How can I get the input to the createuser script?
- is there a more effective way of doing this?

For those just joining us, the "<<" is known as a here-document or a "heredoc", which essentially pipes the next few lines to the command as stdin.  It runs until the matching label specified after the "<<".

Comment: I don't understand your example. Do you want the user to actually type a bunch of stuff followed by SETPASSWORD?

Comment: I'll update the question to explain what a heredoc is

Comment: for clarity, you should change both "SETPASSWORD" to "ENDBEFORETHIS" ^^ that way non-familiar users of bash won't be expecting bash to incorporate the "SETPASSWORD" string into the input stream.

Comment: can a : `{ echo fakepassword ; sleep 1s ; ....... ; } | createuser mynewuser -P` work ? (I can't test right now). Or do use `expect`, pretty good program for these kind of situations.

Comment: Good thinking Olivier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password prompt can be avoided by issuing directly the `CREATE USER` SQL command, which is what the `createuser` command would ultimately do, anyway.

```
~$ psql << EODOC
>create user foo password 'bar';
>EODOC
CREATE ROLE
~$
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a more effective way of doing this?

You should probably look into using [`expect(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Comment: probably, especially if there really is some "don't accept through stdin" thing on these password answers

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons passwords will not be accepted through stdin. using expect will help u on this.

Comment: what's weird is this worked a few months ago.  I can imagine it perhaps previously working only due to a security bug?